# What does it mean that a differential form is invertible

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, group-actions

In the proof of proposition 7.10 of the book of heat kernels and Dirac operators, there is the following statement:

> We define $\theta (\xi) = (X_M, \xi)$ for $\xi \in \Gamma(M, TM), $ then $\theta$ is a one form on M invariant under the action of X such that $d_X \theta = |X|^2 + d\theta $, wich is clearly invertible outside the set $M_0(X)= \lbrace |X|^2 =0 \rbrace.$

What is the definition of an invertible differential form ( or an equivariant differential form) ? And in this example What is the inverse of $d_X \theta $ ?

Comment: Is this an exact quote from the book? It doesn’t look right.

Comment: @Deane I was suspicious too and checked, but surprisingly, this is an exact quote

Comment: @Didier, which book is this? And do you understand what $|X|^2 + d\theta$ means? It looks like the sum of a scalar function and a $2$-form. How can that be?

Comment: It is from *Heats Kernels and Dirac operators* by Berline, Getzler and Vergne. I actually have no clue what the authors mean by that: it may be some self-contained demonitation of this book.

Comment: Maybe there is some natural $2$-form in the context that is an *identity-like* 2-form and $|X|^2$ would mean $|X|^2 \times$ this 2-form, like in the Lichnérowicz formula, where the scalar curvature means scalar curvature $\times$ the identity map?